# Hi All, We are trying to push the data from csv file into elastic search but we are facing the below issue?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Environment we are using : Ubuntu 14.x

[ERROR] 2018-01-25 06:05:03.376 [[main]-pipeline-manager] elasticsearch - Failed to install template. {:message=>"Template file '' could not be found!", :class=>"ArgumentError", :backtrace=>["/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.0.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:31:in `read_template_file'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.0.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:17:in`get_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.0.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/template_manager.rb:7:in `install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.0.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:57:in`install_template'", "/usr/share/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.3.0/gems/logstash-output-elasticsearch-9.0.2-java/lib/logstash/outputs/elasticsearch/common.rb:26:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator_strategies/shared.rb:9:in`register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:43:in `register'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:343:in`register_plugin'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:354:in `block in register_plugins'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1734:in`each'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:354:in `register_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:743:in`maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:364:in `start_workers'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:288:in`run'", "/usr/share/logstash/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:248:in `block in start'"]}

Comment: our config should be like this below:

Comment: Please update your question with your logstash config

Comment: input {
  file {
    path => "/usr/share/logstash/MTGOXUSD.csv"
    start_position => "beginning"
   
  }
}
filter {
  csv {
      separator => ","
      #Date,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume (BTC),Volume (Currency),Weighted Price
      columns => ["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume (BTC)", "Volume (Currency)" ,"Weighted Price"]
  }
}
output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => "http://54.254.156.172:9200"
     index => "bitcoin-prices"
  }
stdout {}
}

Comment: Please see my previous comment

Comment: Besides, you might also want to check my logstash input plugin for gathering bitcoin data from the blockchain: https://github.com/consulthys/logstash-input-blockchain

Answer (score 0):

I wrote [elasticsearch-loader](https://github.com/moshe/elasticsearch_loader/%20sdfs) for that exact issue.
elasticsearch-loader support csv files out of the box with very simple API.
Example usage:

```
elasticsearch-loader --index blockchain --type bitcoin csv /usr/share/logstash/MTGOXUSD.csv
```